# Integrate my own IDP (Similar to okta) and CIAM into BigCommerce store

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, bigcommerce, idp

I have my own IDP and user store which is used by other apps in order to allow users to login. Right now i am trying to spin up a new storefront using BigCommerce ecommerce platform , for this app i need to use the existing IDP and user store so that users who are using the other apps can single sign-on into the new store front app as well. Can anyone please help on where to start on?

I also had a look into the big commerce Login API using which once can able to login using JWT token for the customers existing already in Bigcommerce platform, But in my case all my user data are store in my custom IAM and i need to log those users into store front seamlessly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide BC Login API with a signed JWT. That JWT needs to contain the BigCommerce userId to enable it to login. To create the JWT you will need a client ID that can be created by creating an app in your developer account, thus creating the trust and not requiring credentials, just a userId.

This gives some help on creating the JWT and all the info required within it:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/customer-login-api

And this is a simple example of it working using Express middleware and Auth0:

https://github.com/bc-simonpallister/bc-auth0-oidc

Answer (score 0):

For BigCommerce Single Sign On (SSO), you can definitely use the following information mentioned - https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/customer-login-api

But as I understand, you are also looking for a seamless solution for BigCommerce SSO wherein you can skip the complex coding part.
**If this was interesting, here is the entire scoop for your reference -**
https://www.miniorange.com/integrations/bigcommerce-sso-mfa

*PS: You can also enable auto sync using above solution in case you wish to provision your users/groups in future.*